# Is there any way to stop triggering vuejs watch methods when the value is changed by the method itself?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

```
watch: {
        alert() {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.alert = "";
          }, 4000);
        }
      }
```

Here, alert method is first triggered by the DOM and its triggered again when the value is changed by the method. is there any way to stop repeating?

My goal is here to check if the value of 'alert' is changed and if it's changed, I want to reset the value after 4s and also count how many times it was changed.

Comment: Put a `change` handler on the DOM that does the changing, since you want to distinguish data changes that are made in the DOM from those that aren't.

Comment: Or use a method for updating the `alert` text and [$emit](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit) its changes instead of using watches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following Roy J suggestion, try putting a `change` handler on the DOM instead of using a watcher.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      alert: '',
      alertCounter: 0,

      resetTimeoutId: null,
      resetTimeoutDelay: 1000, // 4000
    }
  },

  methods: {
    reset() {
      this.incrementAlertCounter()
      this.handlePreviousResetTimeout()
      this.resetTimeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        this.alert = ''
      }, this.resetTimeoutDelay)
    },

    handlePreviousResetTimeout() {
      if (!this.resetTimeoutId) return
      clearTimeout(this.resetTimeoutId)
    },

    incrementAlertCounter() {
      this.alertCounter += 1
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model="alert" type="text" @change="reset">
  <span>{{ alertCounter }}</span>
</div>
```